# Air Still and Pure Turbo Yeast

Tags: fermentation, yeast

i just got my brand new Air Still Kit . the kit include Pure Turbo Yeast and from what i read the manufacture of Air Still advice to only use this Yeast when distilling with Air Still .

the problem is this isn't Clean yeast really . I'm planing to use Lutra Kveik Yeast . from my experience with Lutra this is actually the cleanest yeast i have ever found

since we are using pot still basically it's important for me to have a very clean fermentation in order to have clean distillation

What you think about changing Yeast for those who have experience with Air Still ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we don't talk about distilling here (see guidelines), but indeed, we can talk about fermentation.

What I think is mostly necessary is that you use a yeast which finishes fermentation and then flocculates out quickly so as to leave not much yeast in your fermented liquid. I think that a kveik yeast fits the bill, these normally ferment out fast and deep, and flocculate quick.

I also see in the instructions that after fermentation a fining is done with Turbo Clear, so really, you can use any yeast you want. They would like mostly to sell fermentation kits. And you can buy Turbo Clear separately, so you do not need to purchase their fermentation kit.